# I have a router acting as the wireless connection point for my PC. I have to restart often to get the connection to the main router back

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

I apologize if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find it anywhere specifically.

I have a router set up to wirelessly receive signal from a main router(the one connected to the modem) and I often have to restart the router connected to my PC to receive the signal again. I thought this may be due to a weak signal but I have checked the status of the router and this is not the case. The speed I get through the router is also stable and the highest possible on my network so this also begs the question of what is going wrong when it does actually disconnect.

I understand this is not a support community but helping me to understand the networking side of things may help me fix this issue so I'd appreciate any relevant information.

the router connected to my computer is a tp-link AC1750

Comment: You should give us more information. Are you setting up your AC1750 in "wireless bridge" mode? Does your AC1750 get an IP from your main router and then assign a different IP to your PC? Does your other wireless devices, like smartphones, experience similar disconnects?

Comment: @someuser I am setting it up in wireless bridge mode. I am uncertain about those other questions but I will look into those. thanks for the help pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @someuser forgot to include this:  I use this router solely for the purpose of connecting my pc to the wifi as it does not have this function internally.

Comment: It sounds like the router (acting as an AP client) has crappy firmware. See if you can flash it with dd-wrt

Comment: @davidgo this sounds like a fun easy project. hopefully I'm not mistaken but I'll give it a shot